# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2022_06_02/10/22_17_06.txt' error while writing scraped data to a txt file

Tags: python, selenium, datetime, selenium-webdriver, python-datetime

Code trials:

```
def save_data(data):

    name = f"{dt.now().strftime('%Y_%M_%D_%H_%M')}.txt"
    with open(name, 'w') as file:
       file.write(data)
```

I have this function that should save scraped data to a txt file but I keep getting:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2022_06_02/10/22_17_06.txt'
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: to get the proper date of today you should use `'%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M'`

Comment: Also it seems to not read the file at all what is the folder structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2022_06_02/10/22_17_06.txt'
```

...implies that your system was unable to locate the file *`2022_06_02/10/22_17_06.txt`*.

This line of code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

name = f"{dt.now().strftime('%Y_%M_%D_%H_%M')}.txt"
```

does creates the variable `name` with the value *`2022_06_02/10/22_17_06.txt`* but atleast my localhost which is [windows10](/questions/tagged/windows10) based won't allow to create any file by the name `2022_06_02/10/22_17_06.txt` as it is a ***invalid filename***.

Snapshot:

[image: invalid_filename]

Comment: ohhh yeah got it changing the name worked thankuuu